# Previous + Next div swap better way

Tags: jquery, html, swap

I've been searching all day here and elsewhere to figure out a way to make something work that I initially figured was pretty simple.  I think I finally have it working, but know there has to be an easier way.  After banging my head against the wall I'm giving up on my search and just begging someone to show me how to do this the easy way.

Here's what I need to do.  On several pages of a site, I have a "Previous" and "Next" button that swaps which "div" is active on another portion of my page.  Whichever div becomes "active" at a given time needs to be given the class "active" in order to trigger other events like a video starting to play, a sound effect, an animation, etc.  The same script needs to be able to be called from one of any number of pages, and the total number of "swappable" divs will change depending on the page.  If the Previous button is pressed while the "first" div is active, or the Next button is pressed while the "last" div is active, no action should be taken.

Below is my javascript

```
function swap(what) {
"use strict";
var theDivs = [], i;
$(".PortSwap").each(function() {
    var cid = $(this).attr("id");
    theDivs.push(cid);
});
for (i = 0; i < theDivs.length; i+=1) {
    if ($("#" + theDivs[i]).hasClass('active')) {
        var curDiv = i;
    } 
    $("#" + theDivs[i]).removeClass('active');
    $("#" + theDivs[i]).hide();
}
if (what === 1) {
    if ((curDiv + 1) < theDivs.length){
        $("#" + theDivs[curDiv + 1]).addClass('active');
        $("#" + theDivs[curDiv + 1]).show();
    } else {
        $("#" + theDivs[curDiv]).addClass('active');
        $("#" + theDivs[curDiv]).show();
    }           
} else {
    if ((curDiv - 1) >= 0){
        $("#" + theDivs[curDiv - 1]).addClass('active');
        $("#" + theDivs[curDiv - 1]).show();
    } else {
        $("#" + theDivs[curDiv]).addClass('active');
        $("#" + theDivs[curDiv]).show();
    }
}
}
window.onload = function () {
    "use strict";
    var pDivs = $(".PortSwap"), k;
    for (k = 0; k < pDivs.length; k += 1) {
        if (pDivs[k] !== -1) {
            $(".PortSwap").hide();
        }
    }
    $('#swap0').show();
    $('#swap0').addClass("active"); 
};
```

Below is my html

```
 <div id="content">
  <div id="ncholder">
    <div id="ncframe"></div>
    <div class="PortSwap" id="swap0"><img src="img/nvc1.jpg" alt="Web Screen 1"></div>
    <div class="PortSwap" id="swap1"><img src="img/nvc2.jpg" alt="Web Screen 2"></div>
    <div class="PortSwap" id="swap2"><img src="img/nvc3.jpg" alt="Web Screen 3"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="ncnav">
    <img src="img/backward.gif" alt="Previous" onClick="swap(0)">
    <img src="img/forward.gif" alt="Next" onClick="swap(1)">
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

I'm getting the impression that css isn't important here, and I tried creating a jsFiddle for this but couldn't get it working even though it appears to be working on my test server at the moment.

Help Please!  I'm not new to javascript, though it's been a while.  I am new to jQuery.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
<div id="content">
    <div id="ncholder">
        <div id="ncframe"></div>
        <div class="PortSwap" id="swap0">1<img src="img/nvc1.jpg" alt="Web Screen 1"/></div>
        <div class="PortSwap" id="swap1">2<img src="img/nvc2.jpg" alt="Web Screen 2"/></div>
        <div class="PortSwap" id="swap2">3<img src="img/nvc3.jpg" alt="Web Screen 3"/></div>
     </div>
    <div id="ncnav">
        <img src="img/backward.gif" alt="Previous" onClick="prev()"/>
        <img src="img/forward.gif" alt="Next" onClick="next()"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
$(function(){
    "use strict";
    $('.PortSwap').hide().eq(0).addClass('active').show();
});

function prev(){
    var current = $('.PortSwap.active'), prev = current.prev('.PortSwap');
    console.log(prev.length, prev)
    if(prev.length){
        current.hide().removeClass('active');
        prev.addClass('active').show();
    }
}
function next(){
    var current = $('.PortSwap.active'), next = current.next('.PortSwap');
    if(next.length){
        current.hide().removeClass('active');
        next.addClass('active').show();
    }
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/A7Pce/2/)

Comment: The appears to do exactly what I was asking.  Thank you.  Correct me if I'm wrong, but the console.log(prev.length, prev) can be removed, correct?

Comment: @w00dc4ip yes, that was for debugging purpose only

Answer (score 0):

**Your Solution:**

**Html Code**

```
<div id="content">
    <div id="ncholder">
        <div id="ncframe"></div>
        <div class="PortSwap" id="swap_0">1<img src="img/nvc1.jpg" alt="Web Screen 1"/></div>
        <div class="PortSwap" id="swap_1">2<img src="img/nvc2.jpg" alt="Web Screen 2"/></div>
        <div class="PortSwap" id="swap_2">3<img src="img/nvc3.jpg" alt="Web Screen 3"/></div>
     </div>
    <div id="ncnav">
        <img src="img/backward.gif" alt="Previous"/>
        <img src="img/forward.gif" alt="Next"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

**jQuery Code Only:**

```
$(function(){
    //this will hide all elements with the class 'portswap';
    //Recommend you set the style (CSS) of PortSwap to 'display: none',
    //so as to avoid flash of unstyled content;
    $(".PortSwap").not('#swap_0').hide();
    $('#swap_0').addClass("active");

    $('.btn_nav').on('click',function(){
        var activediv = $('.PortSwap.active').first();
        var activediv_id = parseInt(activediv[0].id.split('_')[1]);
        switch(this.id){
            //execute code when backward button is pressed
            case 'btn_backward':
                if(activediv_id-1 >= 0){
                    //previous iteration of div is present, show it
                    activediv.removeClass('active').hide();                                
                    $('#swap_'+(activediv_id-1)).show().addClass('active');
                } else {
                    //No previous div is present, remain on same page.
                }
                break;
            //execute code when forward button is pressed
            case 'btn_forward':
                if(activediv_id+1 < $('.PortSwap').length){
                    //Next iteration of div is present, show it
                    activediv.removeClass('active').hide();                                
                    $('#swap_'+(activediv_id+1)).show().addClass('active');
                } else {
                    //No next div is present, remain on same page.
                }                            
                break;
        }
    }); 
});
```

**Note: Tested and Working**
**DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/FPhsm/**

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the commented explanations for how you made it work.

Answer (score 0):

In this carousel demo, you can have your previous and next controls anywhere on the page (see this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ze7DeIdk3KqSFZzRA1Of?p=preview)). You can also control multiple carousels at the same time by specifying the custom attribute data-carousel on your controls with the carousel selector.

**Html** (partial code, see the plunker for complete demo)

```
<div id="my-carousel" class="carousel">
    <div class="buttons">
        <a class="prev" href="#" data-carousel="#my-carousel"><</a>
        <a class="next" href="#" data-carousel="#my-carousel">></a>
    </div>
    <div class="items">
        <div class="item active">Item #1</div>
        <div class="item">Item #2</div>
        <div class="item">Item #3</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
// executed on document ready
$(function(){

  // get the active item, if it is not the first, set previous as active
  function prev() {
    var $item = $($(this).data('carousel')).find('.item.active');
    if (!$item.is(':first-child')) {
      $item.removeClass('active').prev('.item').addClass('active');
    }
  }

  // get the active item, if it is not the last, set next as active
  function next() {
    var $item = $($(this).data('carousel')).find('.item.active');
    if (!$item.is(':last-child')) {
      $item.removeClass('active').next('.item').addClass('active');
    }
  }

  // bind the controls to the actions
  $('a.prev').on('click', prev);
  $('a.next').on('click', next);

});
```

**CSS**

```
/* make all items hidden by default */
.carousel > .items > .item {
  display: none;
}

/* make active item shown */
.carousel > .items > .item.active {
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: just a hint: Implementing rel=”next” and rel=”prev” instead of classes could improve seo. http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.de/2011/09/pagination-with-relnext-and-relprev.html

Comment: @abimelex: That is true, I edited the plunker to make use of rel. Please let me know if it is correctly done.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and commented explanations.  The selected answer is exactly what I was looking in this particular situation, but I will be referencing your solution for another site I'm building in the near future.